# Best way to move and draw elements on screen

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, opengl-es-2.0, android-canvas

i have a so so general question.
I need to make a screen that deals with dragging and drawing of objects. I will need to have like a predefined rectangle on top of the screen that represents some kind of a sitting table. below that i need to have predefined empty space (like a floor plan) on which will user put those tables into. Those tables need to contain and carry some data with it so i can send it to my server when the drag and drop is finished. Now i am new with drawing things on android and any kind of help or suggestion would be much appreciated! Thanks :D

Comment: are you rendering with openGL or is that a Canvas?

Comment: I am not using anything, yet .. I am curious what is the best approach because as i said, i dont have any experience with graphics on android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's simple, stick with a custom `View` that represents your entire world. Keep track of the Table and other spaces as data structures, then draw them in the `onDraw`. This is similar to how you'd code up a simple game. Here's an article that goes into more detail: http://cjds.github.io/2014/04/28/Creating-a-simple-android-game/